# How to use Session state mode : SQL Server with VS2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I want to use that session state, because Inproc is unreliable. I need to set that mode in the config file, but dont know how.. can someone help me?

Exception i got from aspnet_regsql tool

```
xception:
```

Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

---

### Details of failure

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString)
   at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString)
   at System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install)
   at System.Web.Management.ConfirmPanel.Execute()

Comment: Is it bad form to ask something that's the *first answer* in google?

Comment: really, i did look in google. i didnt find an easy answer.. not as easy as Aristos provided me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have create on sql the session database you need first to run a tool to create it using the [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx) tool.

```
DATABASENAME = AnyNameOfServerState
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regsql.exe -ssadd -sstype c -d DATABASENAME -E
```

More for this tool: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(VS.80).aspx

Second you can connect using Integrated security and not use user name and password.
Set this on connection strings

```
<add name="SqlState" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;DataBase=AnyNameOfServerState;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

This go to system.web

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="SqlState" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
```

Some more details. If you go to your net directory you see a list of files with .sql extention. One of this is the InstallSqlState.sql, this is the one that the tool runs to create the database. If you open it you can see what is run.

Comment: Aristos. How do i use the tool with visual Studio 2010?

Comment: @Matric001 this is a command line tool, you open a cmd window and you just run the command one time on your computer. On the server I hope that your provider have done that all ready. In the case if you just move the session database to your server local dir and use it, you need to be sure that you trigger every minute the clear tool.

Comment: @Matrix001 to open the cmd window, ->Start->run | type cmd and press enter. Then change the directory to your last net framework directory.

Comment: I run the tool as a wizard without any command line.. i put the AnyNameServerState..in the option of server name..but it gave me an exception of a failure as unable to connect..see above

Comment: @Matrix001 probably you do not have install the sql server. Do you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a StateServer. You can following the step-by-step guide here

http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2009/06/steps-for-session-inproc-mode-to.html

I hope you know the pro/cons of each of the session states so you can choose the right one for your application.

Comment: SQL server is more reliable.. Reliability is key to me.. StateServer is more if the user uses multiple web applications that are on different servers